# Change Hash keys from String to Symbol

Tags: ruby

I need to change the keys of a Hash, I am currently given the key as a String and I need it to be the normal key of a hash. I leave the example below.

I have tried some methods that I found as Symbolize_keys, but they have not worked, says that the method does not exist and I use it as it is in Ruby's Apidock.

i have this:

```
hash = {"name"=>"Jhon","lastname"=>"Doe"}
```

and i need to convert This:

```
hash = {:name=>"Jhon",:lastname=>"Doe"}
```

Thanks Friends

Comment: I guess `symbolize_keys` is only available when working with Rails. The most known way to do it is `hash.map { |key, value| [key.to_sym, value] }.to_h`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Strings *are* perfectly normal keys of a hash.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, its works!!! :) Machine!!

Comment: Jorg, and how print? i tried hash[:name] but it says nil

Comment: You can do `hash['name']`  and that works.

Comment: If you want to retrieve a value from a hash, you obviously need to use the same key you used to store it.

Comment: Thank you all, I already managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Ruby 2.5:

```
hash.transform_keys!(&:to_sym)
```

Comment: Thanks, i use 2.4.2.

Comment: ETA for Ruby 2.5 is 12/25, btw